# Azure web chat testing shows "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized"

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I depolyed my microsoft bot to azure. After deployment I went to check my bot response through "Test in Web Chat", But it shows message could not send, So I went to channels and view my web chat then it shows "**There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized**".

Where I missed ? I do not do any mistakes in **microsoft app id and microsoft app password**. I correctly updated that.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does you .bot file have a production endpoint?

Comment: You are right, I resolved the problem

Comment: @Prakash please share how did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the 'production' endpoint in the .bot file. This needs to be added by the developer after deployment, along with App Id and App Password. If your bot file does not have a production endpoint and you don't have the app id and password stored somewhere else, you will have to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) guide to register your bot on the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered here: ["There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66467234/there-was-an-error-sending-this-message-to-your-bot-http-status-code-notfound/69172072#69172072)

But I'll paste the answer here as well for convenience.

> What solved my problem was changing the Protocol Setting of the App Service. IF you've deployed your bot using Bot Composer, in the resource group you will find 2 App Services -- one with a 'qna' suffix and the other without. Choose the one without the 'qna' suffix.

> Select the App Service --> TLS/SSL settings --> HTTPS Only --> On

> [image: Image for reference]