# There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized - Python Bot Framework Solution

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, botframework

I'm facing the following problem when I want to test my bot in Web Chat:

[image]

I'm using [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/02.echo-bot) from BotBuilder Samples, the bot is based on Python3.8. For deployment, I use [this configuration](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/templates/python-to-linux-webapp-on-azure.yml) with the startup command `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --worker-class aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker --timeout 600 app:APP`. Gunicorn is installed within `requirements.txt`. Deployment is successfull.

What I already done:

1. Checked if the MsAppId and AppPassword are correct, and they are.
2. Checked messaging endpoint to start with **https**.
3. Made an AppService be HTTPS only.
4. Changed host from **localhost** to **0.0.0.0** in `app.py`
5. Changed PORT to **8000** in `config.py` and added **WEBSITES_PORT** with value **8000** in AppService configuration.

What can be the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure web chat testing shows "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395443/azure-web-chat-testing-shows-there-was-an-error-sending-this-message-to-your-bo)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Hi, this is not the answer to my question since I've already done those steps and unfortunately, they didn't help me.